# Revert vertex position to Basis Shape Key

Tags: modeling, vertices, shape-keys

How I can revert the position of a single vertex in a shape key to it's position in the Basis Shape Key?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use **Blend From Shape**:

1. Select all vertices whose positions you want to reset,
2. Execute **Blend From Shape**, accessible from <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or **Vertex** > **Blend from Shape** menu,
3. Set "*Basis*" as shape key to blend from (by default),
4. Set blend factor to the maximum value 1.0 (by default),
5. Uncheck *Add*, so only values from "*Basis*" will be blended in, effectively reverting all selected vertices' position.

Comment: The UI for the "Blend From Shape" panel appears in the bottom-left, as seen in this screenshot: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66636

Comment: In Blender 2.8, instead of "Mesh -> Vertices", the "Blend From Shape" button is in "Vertex -> Blend From Shape". When you click it, a small menu will open in the bottom left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 7):

Found an imperfect solution.

- Go to Edit mode.
- Select the Vertices you wish to reset.
- Select the shape key you want to modify.
- Use "Blend From Shape" from the specials menu (`W` key on the 3D view while in edit mode)
- In the "blend from shape" tool properties select BASIS shape key.
- Blend to 1.0
- Turn OFF the "Add" checkbox

That should cancel out the effect of the current shape.

[image]

Comment: Why is this imperfect? It works perfectly to restore vertices from basis that have been moved by mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## To create a new shape key from the basis:

You could set the *Value* of all the shape keys to `0`, then press the [image: down arrow] button *> New shape from mix*:

[image]

Another option is to *Mute* the shape keys by pressing the eye icon:

[image]

## To copy the location of a single Vertex:

### Method one:

One way is to manually copy the vertex location from the basis key to the shape key in question:

1. With the Basis key active, go into edit mode and select the vertex.
2. Copy (hover over the value you want to copy and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) the coordinates in the *Properties panel* (<kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D view) *> Transform > Vertex*.
3. Select the shape key and paste the coordinates into the *Properties > Transform > Vertex* coordinates:

   [image]

Note that you will have to do this three times, once for each coordinate.

### Method two:

Another way is by using a Vertex group:

1. Select the vertex(s) from which you want to preserve the location.
2. Invert the selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>)
3. Create a new [Vertex group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html), and assign it to the selection.
4. In the shape key, set the vertex group value under *Blend* to the new vertex group (note that this will only work if the *Relative key* is the *Basis*):

[image]

Comment: My intention is to revert the changed position of one vertex in a Shape Key (example: Key 1) to the position of that vertex in the _Basis Shape key_

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem. The situation was that I couldn't change vertex groups. So to solve that problem there is an option:

1. Select your vertices
2. Select shape key with right shape you want (base in this case)
3. Go to *Mesh > Vertices > Shape Propagate*

Attention with this tool, it will move vertices to all Shape keys. It's more like reset, but to all others keys.

If you want only for one shape key, you have to make a "backup copy" of your mesh and transfer only that one shape key.

Hope that helps some.