# How to copy the vertex position to the inbetween values of the shapekey? (Not Basis)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, keyframes, shape-keys

I see no one is talking about this but I'm wondering if there is a way where you can edit the models like say copy from 0.500 to  1 in my current shape key  so I can edit it easier similarly to how maya function works because in blender from what I've known so far (Since I'm still fairly new in this)  keyframes can only be set for timing with already pre-existing deform which is locked to the shapekey values rather than actually editing the vertex.  I do not want to change the basis because I already have set to default.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66634/update-a-shapekey-basis-from-another-shapekey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the drop-down arrow in the Shape Keys panel there is an option for 'New Shape From Mix' - this creates a new shape key from the mix of all your existing shape keys and values.

Simply set your shape key 'values' to set 0.5 for the key you want to get the 'half-way' position of and select 'New Shape From Mix'. This will create a new shape key that produces that distortion when fully set.

[image: New Shape From Mix]

You can use the same method to create a new shapekey from a mix of any amount of any number of your existing shape keys.

Comment: Yeah I know that but I do not want to create new shape key from a mix where it sets to one where I have to slide it to get to my preexisting position  but rather I want to hold it from the last shape keys to copy in frames from 0.500 to 1 and I do not want to change my basis because it will mess up my defaults.

Comment: Sorry - I don’t really understand your issue then, I’m afraid.

Comment: I found what I'm looking for.I simply checked the corrective shapekey addon and set my existing shapekey to the pose I want  to retain like first moving the values to .500 as full pose and  duplicated the mesh.I went to the drop down arrow in the shapekey panel to select **"Add as corrective pose shape delta ( slow, all modifiers + other shape key values)** where I select the first object  (duplicated one) as shape key to second object (original mesh) for the current pose while maintaining my existing shape key deformation values after I moved the slider value to 1 and pasted on that spot.