# Removing Rig and Weights in Blender

Tags: rigging

I have a shirt I made in Blender. I have spent a lot of time on it and therefore would like to re-use it. I would like to remove the current rig as well as the weights. How do I do that? (I want to do this because the garment seems to be retaining its old shape even though I have reworked the mesh. If I could clean everything out, then I'd know if the problem is in the mesh itself and not the rig or weights.)

Thank you!

Sabia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of shapekeys sounds like it might be a more likely possibility than the armature, if you made the changes to a shapekey instead of the base mesh, the basis shape will still be available to return the mesh to it's old shape. Note that in this case just deleting the shape key will remove the altered shape that you have done. [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2941/935) may help in that case.

[image: shape keys with drivers]

If you created shape keys and setup drivers (the purple values have drivers) to allow the armature to control them they can also deform the mesh. The drivers can be removed by right clicking on one of the purple values and selecting delete driver.

The armature modifier is the link that allows the armature to deform the mesh. By deleting the armature modifier you remove any effect it can have. You can also try disabling it first by disabling the eye icon.

[image: armature modifier]

The armature modifier uses the objects vertex groups to know what vertices each bone moves, by removing all the vertex groups you will remove any trace of the previous armature and will need to redo any weight painting.

[image: a mesh's vertex groups]